# What is the meaning of homology in the context of modules?

Tags: ring-theory, homology-cohomology

In the context of sequence of topological spaces, we understand the homology as representing the amount of holes in a space. I have found that, one can also define homology for chain modules. However, I am a bit puzzled in the meaning behind it, could some light be shed on this?

Comment: Homology of spaces is the homology of a certain chain complex. What chain complex is used depends on the homology theory, but homology is by definition quotients out of a chain complex of abelian groups/modules/rings/whatever Abelian, or maybe even additive, category one works in. The homology of chain modules is the core theory: the homology of spaces or whatever is a choice of a complex and a choice of interpretation of what the homology groups/modules/whatever actually represent

Comment: The homology of a chain complex measures the failure of the chain complex to be exact: if the homology groups are all zero, it's exact, but any spots where they are not zero represent failures of exactness.

Comment: that feels like writing the definition again @JohnPalmieri

Comment: "Which chain complex depends on homology theory". Thank you this was pretty deep. Couldn't find it any book lol @FShrike

Comment: "That feels like writing the definition again" - not really. Any and all intuition about what a homology theory "means" comes from an interpretation/intuition for what "a failure (for the boundary maps between complexes) to be exact" means. In simplicial homology, this is supposed to represent holes: a failure of exactness is precisely a failure for all """cycles""" to be the boundary of some higher piece of space, """holes that aren't filled in""" (loosely) (disclaimer: I haven't studied homology properly yet)

Comment: There is even a precise definition of "homology theory" (I don't know it though). An interesting question that I want an answer to: why do we obsess over homology so much? It seems striking that homology and homotopy groups tend to be the only 'tools' really talked about. Perhaps we can do other things with chain complexes, or there is some other analogue of chain complex with a different operation of great use, waiting for someone to find it

Comment: The homology of a chain complex measures how far the chain complex is from being exact. It is as simple as that. Anyone looking for some elaborate teleological intuition is going in for a disappointment.